# Finding an interval in which all the real roots of a polynomial lie

Tags: polynomials, roots

I'm making a program which uses simple bisection method to find the roots of a polynomial. For me to implement this method, I need a rough interval where it can be said with absolute certainty that all the roots are lying. I wasn't quite able to find such a method.

Comment: What if the polynomial has no real solution?

Comment: How many degrees should the polynomial have at most ?

Comment: A two-second Google search of "bounds of polynomial roots": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Polynomials_with_real_roots

Comment: Maybe _Sturm sequences_ can help you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem

Answer (score 4):

Up to division by a constant, $$p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$

Call $M=\max\{1,\lvert a_0\rvert,\lvert a_1\rvert,\cdots,\lvert a_{n-1}\rvert\}$

For $\lvert x\rvert\ge 1$, by inverse triangular identity you know that $$\lvert p(x)\rvert\ge \lvert x\rvert^n-nM\lvert x\rvert^{n-1}=\lvert x\rvert^{n-1}(\lvert x\rvert -nM)$$

So, for $n\ge2$, $p(x)\ne 0$ as soon as $\lvert x\rvert\ge nM$.

So, all the real roots of $p$ must lie in $[-nM,nM]$. This does not guarantee the *existence* of roots in that interval (because $p$ might not have any). However, to check it there's [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Extend to complex plane, you can use [Rouche's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) to conclude that zeros of polynomial $a_nz^n+...+a_0$ (where $a_n\neq 0$ and $a_0\neq 0$) lies in $A(0;r,R)=\{r<|z|<R\}$ where $R=1+\frac{\max\{|a_j|:0\leq j\leq n-1\}}{|a_n|}$, $r=(1+\frac{\max\{|a_j|:1\leq j\leq n\}}{|a_0|})^{-1}$. See [Problem 6](http://www.math.uci.edu/sites/math.uci.edu/files/Qual%20Complex%20September%202015-1.pdf).